# having problems while rendering in Maya 2008

Tags: 3d, rendering

I am having problems while rendering in Maya 2008.

1 frame is taking 1 hr.

My 5 computers have config of : core i3 , 1 gb ATI radeon graphics card, 8 GB Ram.

OS: win Xp pro 32 bit.

I am giving render from command prompt.

What should be my page file size ?

How to diagnose if any problem ?

suggest tips to improve rendering time and quality ?

Also heard there are scripts and tools for rendering ?!!

I am a total newbie to maya, 3d etc and i have team of 3d artists who have inability to google and solve problems independently( due to lack of english knowledge and exposure to net) !

Comment: Which renderer do you use? Mean maya software, mental ray? Another else?

Comment: -1, off topic...

Comment: i gave -1 also. This is not right place to ask

Answer (score 1):

1 frame could take several days or a few milliseconds to render depending on the renderer, the configuration of the renderer, the complexity of the scene, the lighting and so on. Mostly it's about configuring the render though, trading off quality for speed.

This doesn't sound entirely on-topic for Game Development though. Where I come from we use progressive renderers that constantly improves on the rendered frame(s) until the time/deadline is up - that way there's much less guesswork. We're just telling the renderer that we have x amount of time so please go ahead and render this scene/animation as pretty as possible until the time is up ^^

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is great example of offtopic. But i will recommend you to use some of the gpu or gpgpu renderers. If you dont own renderfarm it is great way how to render 10-300 times faster in same quality. There are some renderers to consider.

**CPU rendering is dead**

- [iray](http://www.mentalimages.com/products/iray.html) Is gpgpu raytracer from Mental Images, authors of Mental Ray
- [V-Ray](http://www.chaosgroup.com/en/2/vray.html) Most famous and really good gpgpu renderer.
- [FurryBall](http://furryball.aaa-studio.eu/) is the fastest renderer
  for Maya, works like game engine and that means best speed, but bad support for indirect lighting.

Comment: thanks for replying to offtopic question! Do tell the right stackoverflow family site where i can put more such questions.

Comment: my team says vray would take double time but quality will be good.  i did not knew that before! I hope my client accepts the work...and any option to improve quality after rendering from maya default render option ?!

Comment: Vray would take double time? No ... It will be much faster. For speeding up, try to turn off some of secondary rays - mean most of indirect lighting (maybe you dont need it at all...), use less values for antialiasing ...

Comment: Try some CG artist forums. Not game developers QA. You will most propably not get your answer here.